# Python returns error when retrieving large amount of records from API

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a project that needs to access an API that returns a JSON with the data from a checklist that the user has completed, it contains all the data, but the user can also evaluate some points such as: choosing several options or an option, answering a text, answer a number, etc. These assessments come in another endpoint by passing the assessment ID.

So, I created the following code. It takes the result of the "general" endpoint and takes only the ID to be used as an index to use as a parameter in the endpoint link.

```
evaluations_array = df_evaluations_results.evaluationId.unique()
df_itens = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame()
for index in evaluations_array:
  response = requests. Get(f'https://.../{index}/results', headers=headers)
  texto = response.text
  data = json.loads(texto)
  df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'])
  df_itens = df_itens.append(df, ignore_index=True)
df_itens
```

It returns the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

The type of JSON that is returned is in the following format:

```
[
{
    'resultId': <value>, 
    'evaluationId': <value>, 
    'categoryId': <value>, 
    'itemId': <value>, 
    'scaleId': 1010, 
    'answeredAt': <value>, 
    'evaluative': None, 
    'text': None, 
    'number': None, 
    'stateId': None, 
    'cityId': None, 
    'product': None, 
    'competencePeriodId': None, 
    'selectedOptions': [
        {'optionId': <value>, 'optionText': 'text', 'optionValue': None}, 
        {'optionId': <value>, 'optionText': 'text', 'optionValue': None}, 
        {'optionId': <value>, 'optionText': 'text', 'optionValue': None}
    ], 
    'index': None, 
    'originalWeight': <value>, 
    'maximumWeight': 0, 
    'obtainedWeight': 0, 
    'comment': '', 
    'countAttachments': 0, 
    'countSignatures': 0
}
]
```

I think the problem may be in the 'selectedOptions' field which is multivalued and from what I'm understanding, it's understanding the keys of 'selectedOptions' as indices.

What I can't understand is that when I return small data records it doesn't return errors. When it returns a large number of records, it generates this type of error.

Comment: I don't get any error in the json you gave example. If you provide the json data you get this error, we can find out what the problem is.

Comment: It's the same with me. I can't send you the data because is from the company what I work and it's confidential. I can't get any errors but when I receive a large amount of data. So, it don't make any sense because with small dataset the notebook runs normally. I think the problem is in a part of the data when I receive the large data.

Comment: ok, I have added a code as an answer where you can see the data you get an error, we can continue from there.

Comment: hello, Clegane. I thank you from the bottom of my heart for your help. Your answer helped me to solve the problem. The error_json array showed me just empty arrays. Well, I will investigate a little more the problem and solve this. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the code below. The data you get error will be added to the **error_json** list. Add the error data (if there is any private data, please replace it) to the question. This way we can fix the problem.

```
evaluations_array = df_evaluations_results.evaluationId.unique()
df_itens = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame()

error_json=[]  # we will add the jsons that we got an error to this list

for index in evaluations_array:
  response = requests. Get(f'https://.../{index}/results', headers=headers)
  texto = response.text
  data = json.loads(texto)
  try:             # if there is no error, continue
    df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'])
    df_itens = df_itens.append(df, ignore_index=True)
  except:  #If we got an error in the json normalize function, let's add this data to the list.
      error_json.append(data)
df_itens
```